# Numpy Array Multiplication Differnce in Regular vs when using For loops

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I wanted to apply multiply blend on an image with a completely yellow image.
The image is:
[Eiffel Tower Paris](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ClnT.jpg)

The yellow image is created using:

```
img_paris = img1 = cv2.imread("/content/drive/My Drive/Datasets/Images/paris.jpg")
yellow_image = np.ones(img_paris.shape) * 255 

yellow_image[:,:,0] *= 0
```

I tried two techniques:
Firstly I used the regular multiplication

```
imgc = img_paris.copy()

imgc = (imgc * yellow_image)
```

This resulted in:
[Eiffel Multiplied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTMHm.png)

Then I used for loops to multiply individual elements

```
for x in range(yellow_image.shape[0]):
  for y in range(yellow_image.shape[1]):
    imgc[x,y] = (imgc[x,y] * yellow_image[x,y])
```

which resulted in
[Eiffel Multiplied 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBjlf.png)

The result of second looks like the image is getting inverted somehow.

Both techniques should result in similar results.
Why is the image getting inverted in the for loop technique?
I want to use the For loops for more control. Can someone tell me why is this happening? Why are both techniques result in different results?

Comment: That's not a yellow image in rgb space. It's cyan or so.

Comment: @MadPhysicist `cv2` stores images in the BGR order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The images are different, because the former image contains floating point data and the data type of the later image is `uint8`.

The instruction `imgc = (imgc * yellow_image)` generates a new array with floating point data since the data type of `yellow_image` is floating point.

Create a `yellow_image` with datatype `uint8` to sove the issue:

```py
yellow_image = np.ones(img_paris.shape, dtype=np.uint8) * 255 
yellow_image[:,:,0] *= 0
imgc *= yellow_image
```

---

Alternatively use [`numpy.ndarray.astyp`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html) to create a copy of the array and to cast to `uint8`:

<s>`imgc = (imgc * yellow_image)`</s>

```py
imgc = (imgc * yellow_image).astype(np.uint8)
```

or use [`numpy.multiply`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html), by specifying a casting rule and a type:

```py
imgc = np.multiply(imgc, yellow_image, casting='unsafe', dtype=np.uint8)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in a totally unexpected place: in the creation of `yellow_image`. `np.ones` by default creating an array of floating-point type: hence `yellow_image` is created with float-type elements. Check:

```
>>> yellow_image.dtype
dtype('float64')
```

Hence when you do the following: `imgc * yellow_image`, the resulting array data-type is promoted to the one with higher precision (the floating-point type, of course) and hence `imgc` has elements like:

```
array([[[    0., 24225., 12750.],
        [    0., 23715., 12240.],
        [    0., 23460., 11985.],
        ...,
```

which are of floating-point type.

To avoid this problem, and to not go through the hassle of writing datatypes explicitly, use:

```
yellow_image = np.ones_like(img_paris) * 255
```

`np.ones_like` creates an array of ones with the shape of the array passed to it, and the exact same dtype - removing your worries.
Now check:

```
>>> yellow_image.dtype
dtype('uint8')
```

Now consider `imgc1 = imgc * yellow_image` and `imgc2` is the output of the loop. Check:

```
>>> np.allclose(imgc1, imgc2)
True
```

Problem solved.

**N.B.** - To answer your question about *why the image is inverted*:

When the multiplication results in floating point types, it hold large numbers (24225., 12750., etc) as pixel colour values. When you write an image using this array, all these numbers are clipped to the maximum possible pixel colour value: 255. Thus, most of the image you see is yellow, since all the 'overflowing' values have been clipped to 255, leading to the brightest possible yellow shade.

On the other hand, when the multiplication is done forcing the `uint8` type, any values larger than 255 'roll back' to the smallest possible value of an *unsigned, 8-bit integer*: 0. So if the value is 487, the dtype restriction will force it to be `0 + (287 - 255) - 1 = 31`. This is *overflow*. So a large number can end up becoming very small - the math is simple, look it up. Hence you get an inverted sort of an image (unexpected dark pixels).

Answer (score 2):

> Both techniques should result in similar results. Why is the image
> getting inverted in the for loop technique?

Because you should've done this way, converting data type:

```
imgc = np.uint64(img_paris.copy()) # <-- convert datatype

for x in range(yellow_image.shape[0]):
    for y in range(yellow_image.shape[1]):
        imgc[x,y] = (imgc[x,y] * yellow_image[x,y])
```

---

## Explanation part 1 (dtype)

This is because `dtype` changes when reassigning the full matrix, while it does not happen reassigning slices:

```
a = np.array([[1]], np.uint8)
b = np.array([[1]], np.float64)

a[0] = a[0] * b[0] # assigning slices dtype of a does not change
print(a.dtype) #=> uint8

a = a * b # while assigning the full matrix it does
print(a.dtype) #=> float64
```

**If you print your `dtype` along the way you see this:**

```
yellow_image_1 = np.ones(img_paris.shape) * 255
print(yellow_image_1.dtype) #=> float64
yellow_image_1[:,:,0] *= 0
print(yellow_image_1.dtype) #=> float64

imgc_1 = img_paris.copy()
print(imgc_1.dtype) #=> uint8
imgc_1 = (imgc_1 * yellow_image_1)
print(imgc_1.dtype) #=> float64
```

**And this:**

```
yellow_image_2 = np.ones(img_paris.shape) * 255
print(yellow_image_2.dtype)  #=> float64
yellow_image_2[:,:,0] *= 0
print(yellow_image_2.dtype) #=> float64

imgc_2 = img_paris.copy()
print(imgc_2.dtype) #=> uint8
for x in range(yellow_image_2.shape[0]):
    for y in range(yellow_image_2.shape[1]):
        imgc_2[x,y] = (imgc_2[x,y] * yellow_image_2[x,y])
print(imgc_2.dtype) #=> uint8
```

So you end up with different `dtype` matrix.

---

## Explanation part 2 (OpenCV BGR)

As mentioned, keep in mind that OpenCv uses the [**BGR format**](https://www.learnopencv.com/why-does-opencv-use-bgr-color-format/) and each pixel value goes **from `0` to `255`**, says `np.uint8`.

So, if you are using for example matplotlib, for showing the image you must **swap the B and R channels**:

```
img_paris = cv2.imread('3ClnT.jpg')
plt.imshow(img_paris[:,:,::-1])
```

While this is not required if you are saving using [cv2.imwrite()](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#gabbc7ef1aa2edfaa87772f1202d67e0ce) or [cv2imshow()](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga453d42fe4cb60e5723281a89973ee563), for example:

```
cv2.imwrite('paris.jpg', img_paris)
```

---

That said, you can generate your solid yellow image using this one liner command:

```
yellow_image = np.ones_like(img_paris) * (0, 255, 255)
```

And show it or save it:

```
plt.imshow(yellow_image[:,:,::-1])
cv2.imwrite('solid_yellow.jpg', yellow_image)
```

---

Now, your result from the multiplication `paris_yellow = img_paris * yellow_image` results in a value greater than `255`:

> Clipping input data to the valid range for imshow with RGB data (`[0..1]` for floats or `[0..255]` for integers).

So, when you multiply you end up with a max pixel value which can be `255 * 255 = 65025`.

You then need:

- convert terms of multiplication to a datatype that supports integer up to `65025`
- After multiplication, normalize then convert back to `uint8`

---

This is an example:

```
paris_yellow_2 = np.int64(img_paris) * np.int64(yellow_image) # <- use int64 terms
max_px_val = np.amax(paris_yellow_2) # <-- Max pixel alue
paris_yellow_2 = np.uint8((paris_yellow_2/max_px_val) * 255) # <- normalize and convert back to uint8
plt.imshow(paris_yellow_2[:,:,::-1])
```

And this is the result:

[image]

---

**Other option**, which gives a different result is to multiply the `G` and `R` channels for a coefficient greater than `1` then crop values `>255`. In this case you need to use a float `dtype`:

```
paris_yellow_3 = np.float64(img_paris) * (1, 3, 3)
paris_yellow_3[paris_yellow_3 > 255] = 255 # <- crops to 255 pixels values > 255
paris_yellow_3 = paris_yellow_3.astype(np.uint8) # <- back to uint8
```

In this case `B` is multiplied by `1` (no change), `G` and `R` are multiplied by `3`, giving the following result:

[image]